# How does AEM resolve the JSON extension?

Tags: aem, sling

In CQ, if I request a resource such as `localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.json`, I would get the node information in JSON format. The same applies for the XML extension as well.
My question is, where is it implemented that the node information is rendered in JSON format if the URL extension is `json`?
Basically, the extension is just simply text and another part of the URL structure. Simply appending `json` won't magically fetch the information in JSON format.
Obviously, one would have to use this information to write logic for returning the node information in JSON.

I'm trying to learn about the internal workings of CQ. Maybe the concept of getting JSON is the same in Apache Sling as well? I don't know if it's CQ specific or not, but the point is same. I've tried `/system/console/jcrresolver` as well, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function of Apache Sling. The DefaultGetServlet is invoked on all GET requests. The servlet checks the request's extension and uses the corresponding renderer if it's enabled.

Look through the code of the [DefaultGetServlet](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/DefaultGetServlet.java) and as well as the renderers in this [directory](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers) such as the [HTML renderer](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/HtmlRendererServlet.java), [JSON renderer](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/JsonRendererServlet.java) and [XML renderer](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/XMLRendererServlet.java).

The documentation is located here: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html