# How does adobe experience manager render XML content into a webpage?

Tags: xml, adobe, aem

I'm quite a newbie in AEM(Adobe experience manager), but I heard that you can export XML from it. I have 3 questions regarding this:

- Why not HTML?
- How does AEM process internally to display the XML content?
- How do we render the XML content outside AEM to see the original webpage content in AEM?

Thank you very much and hope to hear back from you soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, AEM can render content in XML and HTML, as well as JSON and others. See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965947/how-does-aem-resolve-the-json-extension/35966223).

You'll want to read the [Sling Cheatsheet](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/platform/sling-cheatsheet.html) and the [Sling docs](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html) regarding Apache Sling script resolution. Read about [Sling rendering with the default Get servlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html).

The same content in the JCR can be rendered in different formats by changing the URL extension. So if you have a `cq:Page` resource at `/content/projectname/page`, you can retrieve XML by making a simple GET request to `/content/projectname/page.xml`. Likewise you can retrieve HTML at `/content/projectname/page.html` and JSON at `/content/projectname/page.json`.

As for your question on how AEM renders handles the rendering internally, it's actually the responsibility of Apache Sling. You can examine the open source code on GitHub including [the different renderers](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers).

Comment: thank you so much @nateyolles! Very valuable information for someone that doesn't have much clue about this question, like me.